# 404 error for /_vti_bin/client.svc

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Whenever I try to save I get this error (via javascript console)

POST https://domain.local/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery 404 (Not Found)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was twofold:

1. My server was missing the `HTTP Activation` in `WCF Services` in the .NET Framework 4.5 Feature.

Go to Server Manager => **Manage** => **Add Roles and Features** => **Features** and make sure it's checked.

2. I had to add the Negotiate-provider for Windows Authentication in IIS.

Open IIS, go the the site in question, open Authentication, right click Windows Authentication, click Providers..., add Negotiate from Available Providers. I'm having it below NTLM and that works fine.